# Enable React-Select option to persist during search?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-select-search

I am attempting to make the first and last option in my react-select component always display in the list.  I don't want it to be filtered out during search.  Is there a way to eliminate an item from being filtered?  I have tried a custom filter see codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-cloud-yql6ms?file=/src/App.js), but it doesn't work.  If I search for a or letter not in the first or last item, it gets removed.  Can anyone provide any assistance? See relevant snippet below:

```
    const customFilter = (option, rawInput) => {
    const inputValue = rawInput.toLowerCase();

    // If there's no input, include all options
    if (!inputValue) {
      return true;
    }

    // Allow the first and last options to always be visible
    if (option.index === 0 || option.index === options.length - 1) {
      return true;
    }

    // Apply regular filtering for other options
    return (
      option.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue) ||
      option.value.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        options={options}
        isSearchable={true}
        filterOption={customFilter}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Forked Sandbox Link** - https://codesandbox.io/s/still-moon-8wwczj

```js
import Select from 'react-select';


function App() {
  const options = [
    { value: 'first', label: 'first', fixed: true },
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
    { value: 'last', label: 'last', fixed: true },
  ]

  const customFilter = (option, rawInput) => {
    const inputValue = rawInput.toLowerCase();

    // If there's no input, include all options
    if (!inputValue) {
      return true;
    }

    // Allow the first and last options to always be visible
    if (option.data.fixed) {
      console.log("from option fixed ====>", option);
      return true;
    }

    // Apply regular filtering for other options
    return (
      option.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue) ||
      option.value.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        options={options}
        isSearchable={true}
        filterOption={customFilter}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an example of how you can fix the first and last item.

**Explanation:**
If you check the **options** array, you will see a key named **fixed**. If **fixed** is true, then those items will show always no matter what. You just need to add **fixed** as true for the first and last item of the options or into whichever item you want to fix.